# Show that $h(x)$ has a minimum at $0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $h:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function that satisfies $x\cdot\nabla h(x)\geq0~~\forall~x\in\mathbb R^n $.

How can I show that h has a minimum at zero? I know that at a stationary point $\nabla h(x)=0$.

Comment: If $\Delta h$ is the gradient of $h$ (by the way this is more commonly written as $\nabla h$), then you're given that the directional derivative in every direction is nonnegative. What does that tell you geometrically speaking about the point in question?

Comment: By $\Delta h(x)$ do you mean $\nabla h(x)$?

Comment: Yes I did mean $\nabla h(x)$. How would I show this rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$ consider the function
$$
 f: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R, t \mapsto h(t \mathbf x) \, .
$$
Then for $0 < t \le 1$
$$
 f'(t) =   \mathbf x \cdot \nabla h(t \mathbf x) = \frac 1t \bigl(t\mathbf x \cdot \nabla h(t \mathbf x)\bigr) \ge 0 
$$
so that $f$ is *increasing.* Consequently, $h(\mathbf x) = f(1) \ge f(0) = h(\mathbf 0) $, i.e. $h$ has a (global) minimum at the origin.